# Parent and Child Shell Script Problem

Tags: shell, variables, scope

I have two scripts parent.sh and child.sh. There is a variable in parent.sh which needs to be accessed by the child process. I have achieved this by exporting the variable in the parent script and the variable is available to the child process?

Is there any way that child can modify the value of the export variable defined in parent shell?

Parent.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
export g_var=2
./child.sh
```

child.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
g_var=`expr $g_var + 1 `   #This modification is available in child shell only.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most shells support the `source` built-in, which executes a script in the current shell rather than spawning a new one. In bash and a few others, the [command `.`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-g_t_002e-108) is equivalent to `source`. I haven't read it, but the POSIX shell standard might require the two to be equivalent. Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
export g_var=2
. ./child.sh
```

"child.sh" is the same as your example.

Answer (score 0):

No (assuming that you mean you need the change propogating *back* to the parent). You'll have to implement some form of IPC (inter-process communication) in whatever fashion to communicate this change.

(A simple way would be for the child to write out a small shell script containing the change, and for the parent to source this script when the child process exits).

Comment: Please provide me some more detail about this implementation

Answer (score -1):

Use below command in child file  - This will export all the variable to temporary file env_file
printenv | sed 's/^/export /;s/=/=\"/;s/$/\"/' > env_file

and then in parent file after calling the child file use below command

./child.sh
. env_file